Convertendo uma Lista de uma determinada classe para outro tipo de classe
Ola
Gostaria de saber como posso estar convertendo uma Lista de uma determinada Classe para outra na minha MVC C#.
  public IActionResult Index()
       {
           List<ClienteModel> ListaCliente = new List<ClienteModel>(_AplicacaoCliente.BuscaLista());
           return View(ListaCliente);
       }

Acima estou tentando receber via API do meu metodo _AplicacaoCliente.BuscaLista() que salva no banco como uma classe "<'ClienteEntidade'>", que tem todas as mesmas classes que a minha model <'ClienteModel'>, porem a mesma diz que não pode converter. Gostaria de saber como posso estar fazendo a conversão?

Você pode usar um Mapper para conversão de classes, uma das mais populares é o pacote AutoMapper: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

O erro que está tendo, é porque não tem como você transformar um campo de uma classe A, para um campo de outra classe B de forma automática. Basicamente o seu código escrito de uma forma mais vísivel, é assim abaixo
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ClienteEntidade clienteEntidade = _AplicacaoCliente.BuscaLista();
    List<ClienteModel> ListaCliente = new List<ClienteModel>(clienteEntidade);
    return View(ListaCliente);
}

Olhe para a primeira linha, você nos mostra que o método _AplicacaoCliente.BuscaLista() retorna um tipo ClienteEntidade, e você está tentando criar na segunda linha, uma lista com um modelo/classe diferente do que você passou por parâmetro.
O que você pode fazer é o seguinte com o código abaixo de exemplo
public class ClienteModel
{
    public ClienteModel(string nome)
    {
        Nome = nome;
    }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
public class ClienteEntidade
{
    public ClienteEntidade()
    {
            
    }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
List<ClienteEntidade> clienteEntidade = new List<ClienteEntidade>();
var clienteEntidade1 = new ClienteEntidade();
clienteEntidade1.Name = "Diego";
var clienteEntidade2 = new ClienteEntidade();
clienteEntidade2.Name = "Julio";
clienteEntidade.Add(clienteEntidade1);
clienteEntidade.Add(clienteEntidade2);
            
List<ClienteModel> clienteModel = new List<ClienteModel>();
var clienteModelDTO = clienteEntidade.Select(t => new ClienteModel(t.Name)).ToList();
clienteModel.AddRange(clienteModelDTO);

No trecho, é onde ocorre o mapeamento de uma classe para a outra usando o atributo que queremos.
var clienteModelDTO = clienteEntidade.Select(t => new ClienteModel(t.Name)).ToList();

